# Issue with Bootstrap tooltips not showing up in the right place

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, css-position

I have the image of a map with several markers - each marker with a class of `.marker` is absolutely positioned and the parent div `#map` is relatively positioned - so far so good.

I'm using [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap) and I'd like to have a [tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) with the name of the location to pop up when a user hovers on one of the markers. The tooltip appears and works as expected, except that it's nowhere near the marker - it's at the top of the `#map` div.

Any ideas as to how I will be able to set the tooltip to appear next to/on top of the marker which is absolutely positioned?

Any help would be appreciated,

Ian

Comment: Could you post your code, maybe in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi I tried doing that to be honest - however I didn't manage to get it working in jsfiddle - I'll try giving it another go...

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this would work with your code (post it?)

Add this to your js:

```
$(function() {
  $('.marker').tooltip({placement: 'right'});
});
```

Or if you are using the `data- attributes`:

```
<div class="marker" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using data attributes. And yes it's set to right. The tooltip always keeps showing up at the top of the `.map` div

Comment: What's the css for the marker class look like, maybe post your css. You could try and remove all the custom styles you have for marker and build it up from there. You could also try the js way of doing it.

Comment: $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(
    {container: 'body', placement: 'right'}
    )

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap tooltips apply over Position relative elements. Make sure your element is position relative, In case not then you need to write css for .tooltip to show in right place.

Answer (score 0):

Easily change tooltip data-placement="left", data-placement="right", data-placement="top", data-placement="bottom"

below mention the code

---

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-push-1">
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger col-md-10" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">Tooltip on bottom</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">Tooltip on right</button>
    </div>
</div>                

<script>
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
});
</script>
```